# ComboBox, PanelBar freeze after postback?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

Have anyone experience same problem like me?

I have a MutiView, in one of the View it contains a UserControl, the UserControl contains a RadComboBox.

Then I have an RadWindow open with client script, once the RadWindow closed, it called the window onclose client script and do a postback to the RadAjaxPanel (it contains the MutiView).

So I can see the LoadingPanel it appears over the MutiView, but after the load, all combobox, panelbar inside the UserControl is like frozen, when I click on the combobox, it doens't popup the list, when I click on the PanelBar, it doesn't expands or minimize.

I hope is not only me? Thanks in advance.

King

Answer (score 0):

After googling I found the same post (probably yours again?) in the telerik forums:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/ajax/combobox-panelbar-freeze-after-postback.aspx

You may expect a reply from the Telerik community there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you receive any Javascript errors? Could you disable the AJAX by setting the EnableAjax property to "false" property of the RadAjaxManager and check whether you will receive any errors.

If this still doesn't helps could you provide your code so we can see what can cause the issue.